# Replace loaded url with another via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not a gold star medal with Javascript, so please bear with me.

We have an addition on the site that is being loaded externally via a a javascript (its called ratecard), however the link that is supplied that the item is being used for isnt correct, so with a little javascript/jquery we are trying to overwrite it.

As the plugin is loaded it adds to a predefined div a location.href. I am trying to overwrite this via following javascript.

This is the div that is being generated

```
<div class="wdgt_widget" style="border:1px solid #1d8be0 !important; border-radius:8px  !important; padding:11px  !important; width:300px !important; height:64px  !important; cursor:pointer  !important; box-sizing: border-box  !important;" onclick="location.href='https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms'"></div>
```

So I am trying to unbind the click action first and add a new one, yet nothing happens. See script below.

```
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#wdgt_widget').unbind();
                    $('#wdgt_widget').attr('click' 'location.href="https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms/review/");
                }, 5000);   
            });
        </script>
```

I added a 5 second timer on it, since i wanted to make sure the code would be loaded and div already be generated.

Sadly nothing happens. Is there a possibility to simply use replace on the onclick? or did i do something wrong here?

Comment: You should be using `.wdgt_widget` instead of `#wdgt_widget`. I Suppose. Since your `div` doesn't have a id.

Comment: and the attribute name is `onclick` not `click`

Comment: And `unbind()` doesn't unbind inline script. And you have synthax error in your posted code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**
1) This `$('#wdgt_widget')` You are using `#` in the selector which is used to select by id. But you have a class in your `div` so use `.`

**Solution:** 1) Replcae the above mentioned syntax with this `$('.wdgt_widget')`

---

**Problem :** 2) You have a missing `'` on the end of the attr function and also a `,` between your `click` and `location`.

`$('#wdgt_widget').attr('click' 'location.href="https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms/review/"); // , and ' missing.`

**Solution:** 2) change `.attr('click' 'location.href="https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms/review/")` to `.attr('click','location.href="https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms/review/"')` 
Note I added a `,` in between and `'` at the end.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I realized as I was posting this already my class and id mixup ... but the command and quote at the end did it for me. Awesome

Comment: @Dorvalla glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.wdgt_widget')
          .unbind()
          .attr('onclick', 'location.href="https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms/review/"');
    }, 5000);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `.wdgt_widget` instead of `#wdgt_widget`. Since your div doesn't have a id.

```
<div class="wdgt_widget" style="border:1px solid #1d8be0 !important; border-radius:8px  !important; padding:11px  !important; width:300px !important; height:64px  !important; cursor:pointer  !important; box-sizing: border-box  !important;" onclick="location.href='https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms'"></div>

<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.wdgt_widget').unbind();
                    $('.wdgt_widget').attr('click' 'location.href="https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms/review/");
                }, 5000);   
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('.wdgt_widget').unbind().attr('onclick' 'location.href="https://ratecard.io/staffing-ms/review/");
  }, 5000);   
});
```